# Is there a way to give roles without a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a database with discord id, seconds and more
A plugin from a game server is measuring player activity and feed it inside the database

I was wondering if there is a way to make my bot give a role to that specific discord id as long as his activity is bigger than some value

ive tried this way but it doesn't work

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)

async def checkDB():
    delete_oldDate()

    list =  get_db_list('players_activity', '*')
    for i in list:
        if str(i[3]) != 'None' and int(i[2]) >= min_activity:
            user = i[3]
            role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, giveawayRole_ID)
            await client.add_role(user, role)
        else:
            print("")
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding roles inside and outside of a command works the same way. `client.add_role` doesn't exist, which is why it doesn't work. The correct function is `Member.add_roles(list_of_roles)`.

Going off of context, I'm gonna assume your `user` is already a `discord.Member` instance, as you're calling it's `guild` attribute. You can also use `Guild.get_role(role_id)` to get the `discord.Role` instance of the role.

```
user = i[3]
role = user.guild.get_role(giveawayRole_ID)
await user.add_roles([role])
```

EDIT:

Apparently your user was *not* a `discord.Member` instance yet, so you'll have to get that first. You should've gotten an error from that though, which you didn't mention. In case `user` is a string, `user.guild` shouldn't work at all either.

First of all, instead of storing their Discord ID as `Mihái#8090`, you should store their *actual* ID, which is a number. You can get this by using `Member.id` whenever they use a command (to put them in the database), or right-clicking them and using `Copy ID` in Discord.

Seeing as you always want to use the same `Guild`, you should already have the `Guild`'s ID stored somewhere as well.

```
guild_id = 000000000000 # Whatever the ID of your Guild is
guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
member = guild.get_member(int(i[3]))
role = guild.get_role(giveawayRole_ID)
await member.add_roles([role])
```

So first get the `Guild` instance, then the user's `Member` instance in that guild, then the `Role` instance, and then give the member the role.

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'guild' sorry, im not a programmer, im just trying to make a bot for a gaming community.
so, to be more specific, inside the database i have 
"steamid" "date" "activity" "discordid"
ex:
 STEAM_0:1:76781613 , 16/4/2014/ 300 , Mihái#8090

inside the loop (@tasks.loop(seconds=30)) checks every row in db and when he finds someone with activitiy > 7 hours lets say, from the db it saves the value of discord id in " i[3] " in my case and then i want the bot to give him a role like "activity"
and when he find someone with activity < 7, remove the role

Comment: If it worked then you should mark my answer as correct